# Tkinter - Run Event Function Upon Listbox Selection

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a ListboxSelect event binding to my listbox, lb. I am using selection_set to select an item in the listbox, but the binded function doesn't run. How can I make the function run when I select an item in the listbox using selection_set as well as when it is clicked?

```
import tkinter as tk

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.lb = tk.Listbox(self)

        for x in range(20):
            self.lb.insert("end", x)

        self.lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", self.OnSelect)

        self.lb.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)


    def OnSelect(self, event):
        print(event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection()[0]))
        self.lb.selection_set(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Even though it is not directly written in Python, this might be related. http://wiki.tcl.tk/13939

Comment: @Lafexlos Thanks for this, got it working, I left the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Lafexlos pointing me to this resource: http://wiki.tcl.tk/13939

What I understood was that you have to generate a virtual event which I then discovered can be done in tkinter using `event_generate`.

```
self.lb.event_generate("<<ListboxSelect>>")
```

The above line can be used to generate an event for the listbox.